# How can I get PowerShell current location every time I open terminal from file explorer

Tags: windows, powershell

I can open PowerShell window in any directory using Windows File Explorer.
I want to run a script every time a new PowerShell window is open and use current directory where it was open in the script.

Using `$profile` let me for automatic script execution but `$pwd` variable does not have directory used to open PowerShell window but has `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. I understand PowerShell starts in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, run `$profile` and next change location used with File Explorer. How can I get file explorer current directory it when my script is executes from `$profile` or maybe there is another way to automatic execute my script after PowerShell window is open?

Comment: while i'm trying to figure this out, i found that when you run powershell from the file explorer, then in the opened console you write `get-history` you'll find that the first command was 'set-location -literalpath <path>'; And as you mentioned, the script in profile will run before this command, so the location will be `c:\windows\system32';
Probably the location (file explorer) is passed to powershell process as argument. but i still can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: Good sleuthing, @Shadowfax; you can examine the invoking command line via `[Environment]::CommandLine` or `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The answer below provides a solution based on the *preinstalled* File Explorer shortcut-menu commands for Window PowerShell.

If *modifying* these commands - which requires taking ownership of the registry keys with administrative privileges - or *creating custom commands* is an option, you can remove the `NoWorkingDirectory` value from the following registry keys (or custom copies thereof):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell
```

Doing so will make the originating folder the working directory *before* PowerShell is invoked, so that `$PROFILE` already sees that working directory, as also happens when you submit `powershell.exe` via File Explorer's address bar.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

[Shadowfax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11532789/shadowfax) provides an important pointer in a comment on the question:

When you hold down Shift and then invoke the `Open PowerShell window here` shortcut-menu command  on a folder or in the window background in File Explorer, `powershell.exe` is initially started with `C:\Windows\System32` as the working directory<sup>[1]</sup>, but is then instructed to change to the originating folder with a `Set-Location` command passed as a parameter; e.g., a specific command may look like this:

```
"PowerShell.exe" -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath 'C:\Users\jdoe'
```

<sup>As an aside: The way this shortcut-menu command is defined is *flawed*, because it won't work with folder paths that happen to contain `'` chars.</sup>

At the time of loading `$PROFILE`, `C:\Windows\System32` is still effect, because any command passed to `-command` isn't processed until *after* the profiles have been loaded.

If you do need to know in `$PROFILE` what the working directory *will* be once the session is open, use the following workaround:

```
$workingDir = [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[-1] -replace "'"
```

`[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` returns the invoking command line as an array of arguments (tokens), so `[-1]` returns the *last* argument, assumed to be the working-directory path; `-replace "'"` removes the enclosing `'...'` from the result.

However, so as **to make your `$PROFILE` file detect the (ultimately) effective working directory (location) *irrespective of how PowerShell was invoked***, more work is needed.

The following is **a *reasonably* robust approach, but note that a fully robust solution would be much more complex**:

```
# See if Set-Location was passed and extract the
# -LiteralPath or (possibly implied) -Path argument.
$workingDir = if ([Environment]::CommandLine -match '\b(set-location|cd|chdir\sl)\s+(-(literalpath|lp|path|PSPath)\s+)?(?<path>(?:\\").+?(?:\\")|"""[^"]+|''[^'']+|[^ ]+)') {
    $Matches.path -replace '^(\\"|"""|'')' -replace '\\"$'
  } else { # No Set-Location command passed, use the current dir.
    $PWD.ProviderPath
  }
```

The complexity of the solution comes from a number of factors:

- `Set-Location` has multiple aliases.
- The path may be passed positionally, with `-Path` or with `-LiteralPath` or its alias `-PSPath`.
- Different quoting styles may be used (`\"...\"`, `"""..."""`, `'...'`), or the path may be *unquoted*.

The command may still fail:

- If the startup command uses prefix abbreviations of parameter names, such as `-lit` for `-LiteralPath`.
- If a named parameter other than the path follows `set-location` (e.g., `-PassThru`).
- If the string `set-location` is embedded in what PowerShell ultimately parses as a *string literal* rather than a command.
- If the startup command is passed as a Base64-encoded string via `-EncodedCommand`.

---

<sup>[1] When you type `powershell.exe` into File Explorer's *address bar* instead, the currently open folder is made the working directory *before* PowerShell is started, and no startup command to change the working directory is passed; in that case, `$PROFILE` already sees the (ultimately) effective working directory.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

1.open the registry (command:`regedit`)

2.find out the path `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command` (not `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command`)

3.the default value should be `powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath "%V"`

4.you can change some param,

> ps: you change the command to `cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"`. if you do so, `shift & right button` in the explorer will open the cmd, not powershell

Comment: Outside the question scope. He's asking how to get the location of powershell when opened from file explorer.

Comment: That's interesting background information, but it doesn't solve the OP's problem, which is about knowing what the working directory _will eventually be_ at the time the `$PROFILE` file is being processed, which happens _before_ the `Set-Location` command is executed.